How can I set an alert on a condition met in an array in Pinescript
I have an array that is being set with divergences. What I want to do is add a conditional statement for IF the array contains cwmacd and macd together and another one that checks IF the array contains vwmacd and macd and rsi.
Here is the array, I just don't know how to check for those conditions and set an alert if the condition is met...
// array to keep all divergences
var all_divergences = array.new_int(44) // 11 indicators * 4 divergence = 44 elements
// set related array elements
array_set_divs(div_pointer, index)=>
    for x = 0 to 3
        array.set(all_divergences, index * 4 + x, array.get(div_pointer, x))

// set divergences array 
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmacd, macd), 0)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmacda, deltamacd), 1)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcrsi, rsi), 2)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcstoc, stk), 3)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calccci, cci), 4)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmom, moment), 5)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcobv, Obv), 6)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcvwmacd, vwmacd), 7)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calccmf, cmf), 8)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmfi, Mfi), 9)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcext, externalindi), 10)

// check minimum number of divergence, if less than showlimit then delete all divergence
 total_div = 0
 for x = 0 to array.size(all_divergences) - 1
    total_div := total_div + round(sign(array.get(all_divergences, x)))

if total_div < showlimit
    array.fill(all_divergences, 0, 0, array.size(all_divergences) - 1)

I think it should be something like this:
if array.includes("macd,rsi", array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y))  //

But I have no idea of that would work or if that's the correct way to check. And also what would I do to set a var so that I can create an alert if that condition is met?
Thanks in advance this will help me a tremendous amount.
